# How to create or change unmanaged computer account to managed computer account in Server 2012R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, wds

My DC Server use Windows Server 2012R2.

I want to use Windows Deployment Service but I don't see any computer account in active directory prestaged devices.

From this [Ref](https://www.windows-noob.com/forums/topic/506-how-can-i-prestage-a-computer-for-wds/), I must change computer account to managed computer account.

But I don't see any this setting about that in computer account.

This is my new computer account image.

[image]

No "Next" Button to Managed Window

What should i do?

PS. I want to post more links and image but I'm newer.I can't post more 2 links. Sorry.

Comment: Did you type in a computer name?

Answer (score 0):

the link you gave in your question points to a very old article, the article outlines steps that are not needed today. Using WDS on 2012 or 2012R2 you can pre-stage a device, join it to the domain and assign it to an OU, as well as linking unattended answer files straight from the WDS console. have a look at the link below

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754469.aspx